# Some difficulties with hair materials

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, materials, particles

I'm a beginner. Currently I'm modeling a Pikachu. I'm having some difficulties with the materials of my pikachu's hair.

Here's a quick render:
[image: Quick render of hair]
Only the edges seem to be on point.

I'm aiming for something similar to this:
[image: example]

The hair is very subtle and almost unnoticeable unless directly hit by a light source. My approach was to add lots of thin and short particles, but it hasn't turned out well. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think it's material doing this subtle look. Are you using Cycles or Blender Internal?

Comment: I'm using Cycles.

Comment: Could you provide blend file? http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ I'll try do something with it.

Comment: Unfortunately, that only accepts <30mb files. Mine is 40. Here is a [gdrive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzwnxg3qrx7DRGgxdjZ2YWc5cW8/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Ok, I'll try on simple sphere. Give me some time.

Comment: I guess the original is not done with hair particles... probably textures, normal map, fresnel...

Comment: @lemon It doesn't have to be exactly like the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Particle edit - Comb, smooth, etc...

The greatest difference I can tell is probably caused by the lack of editing of the hair particles. They are currently pointing outard the faces normal (the default behaviour) like small spikes.

[image]

As you already noticed, the fur look quite short, but in my opinion reducing the lenght can't alone do the job. You'll need to bend it toward the skin by to combing the fur, in the right direction. Take for example the pokemon's forehead fur where you can clearly see that hairs are pointing upward.

[image]

Don't forget to add some variance to the children (e.g. with curl, wave, spiral... kink setting). In the following image you can see the same fur ball combed and with a Curl Kink of 0.002.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not the same as original but it's most subtle I can get with my specs.

### Hair settings:

This is what I can get without Blender crash.

[image: Pika]

[image: Hair settings]

### Material setup:

With *Transluscent* brigtness you can control shadows between hair.

UPDATE:
[image: Material]

Comment: I'll update it with Diffuse changed to Hair (I didn't know about it o_O) it looks better. Try to comb it, I can't, too slow pc.